# Sort by where order

Tags: sql, sql-order-by, firebird

I have query with a where clause like

```
SELECT 
    name
FROM
   adresses
WHERE
   (name ='Peter' AND
   surname = 'Miller') OR
   emailadress1 = 'e@mail.com' OR
   emailadress2 = 'b@mail.com'
```

Example Table

```
name    surname     emailadress1    emailadress2    
------------------------------------------------
Michael             e@mail.com
Jim                                 b@mail.com
Peter   Miller
```

Resulting in:

```
Michael
Jim
Peter
```

Now it seams that the records are sorted as the come in, just like the sort order of the example table above.

But I want to get them in a list where they folow by the where clause order itself. Like

```
name & surname = sortorder 1 
emailadress1   = sortorder 2
emailsadress2  = sortorder 3
```

Example

```
Peter   
Michael
Jim
```

Comment: That is a strange requirement. You might be able to pull it off with breaking it into three queries and a `UNION ALL`.

Answer (score 3):

You an use a `case` statement:

```
order by (case when (name ='Peter' AND surname = 'Miller') then 1
               when emailadress1 = 'e@mail.com' then 2
               when emailadress2 = 'b@mail.com' then 3
               else 4
          end)
```

Comment: One more: How would I select only the first ranking value. Lets say there is only a record on the 2. rated where clause then i would like to only get this as a result.

Comment: Try `select first 1 . . .` or `rows` (http://www.firebirdsql.org/refdocs/langrefupd20-select.html#langrefupd20-select-rows).

Answer (score 1):

Add

```
order by name, surname, emailadress1, emailadress2
```

to the query.

Comment: This is the simplest obvious solution.  Except for the handling of nulls.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to sort them by reverse alphabetical then you would add ORDER BY name DESC to the end of your query.

If you are looking to sort your results by specific people then you would have to add some sort of identifier or ranking to them and then sort by that.

Comment: I want to sort them by the order of the where clause like name and sure = 1; email1 = 2; emails 2 = 3